# Truth table of f(x1,x2,x3,x4) function from given two (4-1) multiplexers

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

Given two (4-1) multiplexers
How can I get the truth table of f(x1,x2,x3,x4) function??
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `4-1` multiplexer has the following general truth-table:

```
A1  A0  Y
 0   0  I0
 0   1  I1
 1   0  I2
 1   1  I3
```

The two control inputs `A0` and `A1` select which of the four inputs is switched through to the output.

To get your question solved, start with the left-hand multiplexer and write a truth-table for it.
In a second step write the overall truth-table by plugging in the intermediate signal values in the general table shown above.

The resulting truth-table has four input columns `X1`, `X2`, `X3`, `X4`.
There is one output column `Y`. Rather than using intermediate truth-tables you could figure out the output value for each of the 16 input combinations.